# Why there is a scroll on x-axis when width is 100vw?

Tags: html, css, dom, width

I've Written that code and it was showing me a scrollbar on x-axis.

```
 nav{width:100vw;}
```

but when i switch the values from vw to % its just starts working fine.

then why is there a scroll with vw?

Comment: For desktops, the browser window is wider than the viewport (adding the scrollbar width), so if you set the width to `100vw` for the element, it will go outside the html.

Comment: There must be some `margin` or `padding` applied to the same element.
You can get rid of this issue in two ways.
1) Highly recommended.
apply `box-sizing: border-box` property to the `body` element.
2) Simple hack
apply width by subtracting the total of `margin` and `padding` values.
eg. if horizontal margin is 5px each side, and horizontal padding 5px each side.
nav { width: calc(100vw - 20px); }

Comment: Use `box-sizing: border-box;` to avoid problems of increasing the width of an element by padding or borders. Be careful with adding a horizontal margin becaus this will always be added to the width of an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because setting width to `100vw` will give `100vw` width to the element + any padding or margins which results in overflow

`100vw element = 100vw width + padding + margin`

which is not the case with 100%;

`100% element = 100% width inclusve of margin + padding`

**Mostly the reason is `body` margin. So set `body -> margin` to `0` and see it working as 100%.**

Comment: Horizontal margin, padding and borders are added to the widht of an element. By using `box-sizing: border-box`, only the horizontal margin is added to the width

Answer (score 2):

% is relative to the parent element. So 100% will take the 100% area of the parent element.

But vw is relative to the viewport directly. Viewport is the visible area of a web page. 100vw is taking the entire viewport width available.

[You can check this article for example.](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/#:%7E:text=There%20are%20four%20viewport%2Dbased%20units%20in%20CSS.&text=Viewport%20Width%20(vw).,1%25%20of%20the%20viewport%20width.)